# Generating 'readable' unique identifier to element in array?

Tags: c++, enums, game-engine

I'm experimenting with making an OpenGL game engine, and initalize the scene like this: (simplified)

Reading the scene.txt file line by line:

- First part: The name of the **Shaders**. I load them
- Second part: The name of the **Materials** which have to created.

  - And the name of the **shader** which will be attached to the material.

So as you see currently I identify 'elements' (like shaders and materials) **by a string** which is not so efficient. (but I think it is acceptable during initialization)

The problem is that if I want to change an object's material or a material's shader during runtime, I have to go through the corresponding array and **compare** its elements' names **(string)** till I find the corresponding one.

I think this is a bit slow, so I would like to know, that how can I make an **unique, easily comparable identifier during runtime**?

Is there a way of "dynamic enum handling" or something like that?

- In other words: How can I identify something which I don't know compile time?
- (using an **int** as identifier is not really a "talking" name)
- **this just came to my mind:**

  - creating an enum for all the **possible** shaders.
  - I create an **array of bools** which contains 1 element for every possible shader.
  - At initalization I set the shader's bool in this array to true if it's loaded.

It's maybe a very bad idea, so feel free comment :)

Comment: You might try one of the standard containers such as `std::unordered_map` to correlate a string with an object.

Comment: Just use an int and that's it. Why not? I really don't understand the array of bools, it wouldn't change anything if you want to find something by name, it would only tell if it's loaded.

Comment: The unordered_map is a good looking thing. :)
@SamiKuhmonen I would like to change the identification base, because strings are slow. The idea at the end of the post is what I thought to replace the string identification.

Comment: Use integer IDs, with a separate ID->name vector on the side for output and debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I chose `std::unordered_map` with `std::string` key values.